# Automatically mount a network drive from a wireless USB adaptor

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, mount, nas, streaming

Here's the plan:

1. I've got a Hi-fi music system that reads music from CDs, iPods, and USBs.
2. All my music is stored on a NAS (ripped from my CDs)
3. The NAS is conneted via Ethernet to my Wifi router and has a static IP address

Is it possible to use a wireless USB adaptor on the Hi Fi system to auto-mount the appropriate folder from my NAS, that way when I plug the wireless USB adaptor to my Hifi it just reads it as a regular USB stick?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work with the setup you describe. You would need a device far more specialized than a USB wireless adapter. The device would need to expose over USB a mass storage device with a FAT32 file-system in it with data in it fetched over wireless from your NAS. No such device is know to exist.

You are better off getting a device that can stream and decode from your NAS and connect the output of that device into the line-in of your Hi-Fi.

Comment: That's what I thought but I'm still not 100% conviced this is not possible. I was thinking of a linux based solution that someone might have. Thanks for your input though.